# How to sort list using <sys/queue.h> functionality?

Tags: linux, macros, queue, linked-list

I have created a LIST using **sys/queue.h** functionality that contains

```
struct stInside{
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct stOutside{
   struct stInside in;
   LIST_ENTRY(stOutside) outq;
};

LIST_HEAD(stOutsideHead, stOutside) head = LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
struct stOutsideHead *headPtr;

struct stOutside *list;

for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
   list = malloc(sizeof(struct stOutside));
   list->in.a = i;
   list->in.a = i;
   LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&head, list, outq);
}
```

I would like to know **How & What** to use in order to sort this list based on the **a** field of the struct stInside. Are there any specific MACROS that could do the job? I saw a

```
#define LIST_SORT_PROTOTYPE(name, type, field, cmp)             \
QHELPER_SORT_PROTOTYPE(LIST, name, type, field, cmp)
```

in **sys/queue.h** but I don't understand how it's working.

Thank you very much for the sharing and your time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this example](http://www.huoc.org/hacks/queueutil_test.c). It uses SLIST and not LIST, but the idea is the same.

Basically you use `LIST_SORT_PROTOTYPE(...)` wherever you would use a sort function prototype, `LIST_SORT_GENERATE(...)` wherever you would use a sort function definition, and `LIST_SORT(...)` wherever you would call that function.